# should i use N:1 both direction in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have N:1 relationship like (member : team)
So, on TeamEntity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<MemberEntity> members = new ArrayList<>();
```

on MemberEntity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
private TeamEntity team;
```

but i would like to design codes which can add member to Team in service classes.
I think i need to use join column with team and member.

My question

1. is it right to use N:1 both direction?
2. how can i make codes to add member to team? if i should use sqld, its fine.

Comment: You can add members to teams with the code you have. Where is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I would ask you if i have to put both @ OneToMany on team and @ ManyToOne on member, or should i just put one of them?

Answer (score 0):

you can just do that :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<MemberEntity> members = new ArrayList<>();
```

on MemberEntity

```
@ManyToOne
private TeamEntity team;
```